# Is there a reliable way to tell how much time is I/O

Tags: linux, timing

I am timing some code and I would like to tell how much of the time taken is due to reading the data in from disk.  I don't believe the result that `time` gives me. For example, I have a 1.3GB file and if I run `wc` I get

```
time wc largefile.file 
  50000000  150000000 1316665179 largefile.file

real    0m26.835s
user    0m18.363s
sys     0m0.495s
```

It can't possibly have taken < 0.5 seconds to read in the file from my old hard drive.

Is there a reliable way to tell how much of the time was due to I/O?

---

Further details for why I don't see how to interpret `time`.  If I do

```
time cat largefile.file > /dev/null

real    0m24.230s
user    0m0.060s
sys     0m1.473s
```

then it is tempting to say that about 22.5 seconds are spent on I/O.  But the `wc` figure from above implies that it is 8 seconds.  These two figures are not consistent.

Comment: Better redo the 2 measurements while rebooting before each one. If the file is even partially in memory then the measurement is false.

Comment: @harrymc I just did `sync && sudo bash -c 'echo  3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches'` first and get the same result.  It's not a caching effect as the overall time is the same.

Comment: sync doesn't clear the memory cache - it just ensures that blocks marked as dirty are written to the disk.

Comment: @harrymc OK but if you don't do the sync the timing is about 0 seconds.

Comment: Because Linux uses the memory cache very effectively, one must be very careful in measuring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sys` means cpu time spent in-kernel, but you want io-wait time.

Googling turned up another stack exchange answer pointing at "[per-process iowait from /proc/$pid/stat](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc)".  (And maybe need to run the programmer under a debugger and set a breakpoint on `exit()` / `_exit()`, so you can read out the iowait before the process goes away ?).

Often I just calculate it by subtracting the cpu time (user+sys) from the realtime.  That assumes the process doesn't wait for things you don't count as "IO".

Comment: Thank you. I added some to the question to show where my confusion lies. Subtracting the cpu time (user+sys) from the realtime doesn't give consistent answers.

Comment: Good point.  I can say why it doesn't: IO can happen "in the background" while the process is still using cpu.  That time is counted as cpu time not io-wait.  Hopefully most programmers understand background writes (see fsync), aka write-back.  Background reads happen because of [read-ahead](https://lwn.net/Articles/155510/).  Maybe we can get what we want by running the task on an idle system (hah) and looking at the read/write milliseconds fields in `vmstat -d`.